# Executing a shell script to automatically connect to my bluetooth speaker with cron

Tags: bash, shell, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I recently set up my Laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and i want it to automatically connect to my bluetooth speakers on startup and everything else is working so far, except for being able to run my script on startup. This is the script i wrote (or rather combined some snippets i found online) and made it executable (`sudo chmod u+x path/to/my/script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

# enable bluetooth
sudo systemctl start bluetooth

#15 sec is enough in my case
sleep 15

# run the program bluez
echo -e 'power on\nconnect MA:CO:OF:MY:DE:VI:CE \nquit' | bluetoothctl
```

I added the bluetooth reciever as a trusted device and already paired it before with my System. Also the script is working so far when i'm running it with `./path/to/my/script.sh`

So i thought i'd just execute it with cron. I added this line into my cron file (via `crontab -e`):

```
@reboot /bin/sh /path/to/my/script.sh
```

But it just does not seem to work. I thought there might be something wrong with my cron version, so i wrote a little control script:

```
touch /some/path/file.txt
```

made it executable and added it to the cron file, it worked both ways (1) at reboot and (2) at a specific time:

(1) `@reboot /bin/sh /path/to/control_script.sh`

(2) `MM HH * * * /bin/sh /path/to/control_script.sh`

the 'file.txt' was created on both tests, but for some reason my script to connect my laptop to the bluetooth reciever won't work when i try to call it with cron. Does anybody have a clue what could cause this? Or maybe has a workaround for this?

Edit: It seems to be an issue with bluetooth turning on to late, if i schedule the script to a specific time where my PC already started it's working. I also removed `exit 0` at the end of the script since i don't think it's necessary

2nd Edit: Also when i set the sleep time stupidly high (100 in my last test) it works as well, so i guess i'll just try it out and find a sleep time thats acceptable and still works. The problem could also be that `sudo systemctl start bluetooth` does not seem to activate bluetooth when i type it into the terminal. So maybe someone has an idea why that is the case? Also when i type `power on` in the bluetoothctl console it says `Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Blocked` even when i enter it with `sudo bluetoothctl`

So the script is working so far, BUT only if bluetooth was turned on in the previous session otherwise it won't activate bluetooth and thus won't do anything.

Comment: after the edit made by you, the question no longer seems to be answered by you. So is there actually a question that you need answer for left?

Comment: yes sry for the inconvenience. I was sitting on this for a couple of hours now and thought i'd ask stackoverflow. As i continued experimenting afterwards i figured out the stuff described in my edits. So yes i could still use an answer for the questions in my 2nd edit. Why won't my bluetooth turn on with `sudo systemctl start bluetooth` and why can't i turn on bluetooth in the bluetoothctl console with `power on` even when i enter the console as root?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script to toggle my bluetooth connection to my speakers, in Ubuntu 20.04. It checks if the connection is already established or not and toggles it accordingly.

Note that it has the MAC address of my speakers hardcoded.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Toggle connection to bluetooth device

mac="90:03:B7:17:00:08" # DEH-4400BT

if bluetoothctl info "$mac" | grep -q 'Connected: yes'; then
    echo "Turning off $mac"
    bluetoothctl disconnect || echo "Error $?"
else
    echo "Turning on $mac"
    # turn on bluetooth in case it's off
    rfkill unblock bluetooth

    bluetoothctl power on
    bluetoothctl connect "$mac"
    sink=$(pactl list short sinks | grep bluez | awk '{print $2}')

    if [ -n "$sink" ]; then
        pacmd set-default-sink "$sink" && echo "OK default sink : $sink"
    else
        echo could not find bluetooth sink
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```